# CircleCI builds are always retried

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, circleci, aws-code-deploy

I'm using CircleCI with AWS CodeDeploy to automate the deployment of my app on EC2 from a Github repository.. The problem is that the build is always getting retried with this message given:
"Looks like we had a bug in our infrastructure, or that of our providers (generally GitHub or AWS). We should have automatically retried this build. We've been alerted of the issue and are almost certainly looking into it, please contact us if you're interested in the cause or if the problem persists."

The last step the build stops after is called: "Bootstrap AWS CodeDeploy"

I don't know whether the problem is from the circle.yml file or the appspec.yml file!

Any Help??

Comment: Hi @Y.A can you post both your circle.yml and appspec.yml? Would love to help you out.

Comment: Here is  my circle.yml:
deployment:
  staging:
    branch: master
    codedeploy:
      Test:
        application_root: /
        region: us-west-2
        revision_location:
          revision_type: S3
          s3_location:
            bucket: *bucket name*
            key_pattern: Test-{BRANCH}-{SHORT_COMMIT}
        deployment_group: *dg name*

Comment: and that's my appspec.yml:
version: 0.0
os: windows
files:
 - source: /
   destination: C:\inetpub\wwwroot

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to see a deployment created on your AWS CodeDeploy console? If a deployment is created, then it means the build process succeeded, but the deployment failed. If deployment is failed, you can try to see the root cause for further investigation. Otherwise the failure should be something related to CircleCI.

Thanks,
Binbin

Comment: No there is no deployment there.. Does that mean I have a problem with the appspec.yml?